# How to prevent Brave browser from redirecting?

Tags: chromium, brave

Whenever I browse to http://localhost:8000, Brave incorrectly redirects to http://localhost:8000/app. It doesn't redirect in incognito mode, nor in Firefox - they both work correctly and show my running localhost application. I've tried clearing my browser cache entirely, and for localhost in devtools, but it doesn't help.

How do I make the browser stay on http://localhost:8000 please?

Comment: Answer is here - hold down refresh button and choose hard reset - https://superuser.com/questions/304589/how-can-i-make-chrome-stop-caching-redirects